# Necessary condition for existence of a positive solution of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I would like to know what are the necessary  conditions of existence of a **positive** (componentwise) solution of the system :

```
          Ax=b,
```

with A a square **singular** matrix, A>=0 and b a vector, b>0 (componentwise).

Thank you for your help.

A.

Comment: By componentwise you mean that all elements of the vector should be positive?

Comment: $x$ will be a vector, how do you define positivity for those?

Comment: Indeed, I mean componentwise.
Furthermore, for my issue, I only need necessary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but I'm giving you a direction for further thinking.

The necessary and sufficient condition for $x >_c 0$ is that, $b$ must lie strictly within the cone formed by columns of $A$. (Note that "$>_c$"  indicate componentwise inequality). This condition holds for any $b$.

Another way to disprove the existence of such an $x$, is to prove that there exists a $y \in R^n$ s.t. $y^T A >_c 0$ and $y^T b < 0$ (Farkas Lemma).